# Some problems with NLTK

Tags: python, tokenize, nltk, counting, corpus

I'm pretty new to Python and NLTK but I had a question. 
I was writing something to extract only words longer than 7 characters from a self made corpus. But it turns out that it extracts every word...
Anyone know what I did wrong?

```
loc="C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CORPUS"
Corpus= CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(loc,'(?!\.svn).*\.txt, cat_pattern=r '(Shakespeare|Milton)/.*)
def long_words(corpus)
    for cat in corpus.categories():
        fileids=corpus.fileids(categories=cat)
        words=corpus.words(fileids)
         long_tokens=[]
         words2=set(words)
         if len(words2) >=7:
             long_tokens.append(words2)


Print long_tokens
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if len(words2) >=7:
    long_tokens.append(words2)
```

with:

```
long_tokens += [w for w in words2 if len(w) >= 7]
```

Explanation: what you were doing was you were appending all the words (tokens) produced by `corpus.words(fileids)` if the number of words was at least 7 (so I suppose always for your corpus). What you really wanted to do was to filter out the words shorter than 7 characters from the tokens set and append the remaining long words to `long_tokens`.

Your function should return the result - tokens having 7 characters or more. I assume the way you create and deal with `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader` is OK:

```
loc="C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\CORPUS"
Corpus= CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(loc,'(?!\.svn).*\.txt, cat_pattern=r'(Shakespeare|Milton)/.*)

def long_words(corpus = Corpus):
    long_tokens=[]
    for cat in corpus.categories():
        fileids = corpus.fileids(categories=cat)
        words = corpus.words(fileids)
        long_tokens += [w for w in set(words) if len(w) >= 7]
    return set(long_tokens)

print "\n".join(long_words())
```

Here is an answer to the question you asked in the comments:

```
for loc in ['cat1','cat2']:
  print len(long_words(corpus=CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(loc,'(?!\.svn).*\.txt, cat_pattern=r'(Shakespeare|Milton)/.*)), 'words over 7 in', loc
```

Comment: The result I get then is: "<function long_words at 0x037EBEF0>".
What did I do wrong?

And another thing, I also need to write something that will count the number of long words per corpus, but len(list) won't work because that will give me a total list, any ideas?

Comment: Your program doesn't seem to be correct in the first place, I'll edit the answer to show you how it should look like - I am unable to test it now, sorry, but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Comment: Odd, I get the error "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'", never encountered that error before.

Comment: I think that `append` was not correct, I just replaced it with `+=` operator in the answer, check it out.

Comment: yes, that works a lot better, I had to make a few small changes but it works now. 
The only thing left now that I don't get is how I can now make a seperate count. The code has to give a result like '100 words over 7 in Cat1' and '200 words over 7 in cat2'
Thanks a million already, I'd upvote your answer but I don't have the necessary reputation yet

Comment: Are 'Cat1` and `cat2` corpus files?

Comment: They are the names of the folders in which the files of the corpus are stored.

Comment: @Nikolaas I edited the answer, see the bottom of it. Can you please mark the question as correct if you are happy with it?

Comment: I used a PlaintextCorpusReader instead of a catigorized one, it works now. Thanks a million!